# why open event of the popup window in the asp.net mvc kendoui grid doesnt work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I used asp.net mvc kendoui to create a new website.I used kendoui grid to create a grid list and used the Popup template window to edit.but when i wanted to test the open event of the popup window,i found it doesnt work.And when i saw the html source code generated by kendoui,i found the js handler did not exist in the grid code.Can anyone help?Anyone had the same issue?
The code like:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<T>().Name("test")....Editable(edit=>edit.Mode(GridEditMode.Popup).TemplateName("Editor").Window(w=>w.Events(e=>e.Open("OpenWindow")))))


<script>function OpenWindow(obj){}</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but Telerik has stated that the events on Popup windows do not work on Razor syntax. You would need to use the grid's Edit event.

[Here is the answer from Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/forums/pop-up-editor-events)

[Here is another solution given on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104426/handling-events-from-a-kendo-mvc-grids-popup-editor-window)